# Which design pattern to use when modelling something that can contain different properties

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I've got a design dilemma.

I have to perform CRUD operations on an entity. Let's call it Report

```
public class Report 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public ReportType ReportType { get; set;}
   //public ?? DetailsTypeSpecific { get; set;} //how to model?

}
```

A Report can be of a specific type that represents what kind of information is going to inform about.

```
public enum ReportType 
{
   DownloadsInfo = 1,
   ClicksInfo = 2,
   UploadsInfo 3
}
```

depending on this type, some reports will contain certain data (in the property DetailsTypeSpecific) and some others will contain other data. For example a Report with type DownloadsInfo will contain things like:

- FileFormat
- IsInCloud
- DownloadedThroughLink

and the reports of type ClicksInfo could have other kind of information. For example:

- UserClicking
- TimesClickedOnSamePage

etc.

A Report will have a button to be exported as an excel file. In other words, a report is excelExportable and I need to provide different implementation for the excel generator depending on the report's type.

Also, the data that the Report contains needs to be added to the Report class as a property, and here's the problem. I don't know how to model it.

Sometimes I will need to retrieve Reports from database, and I need to deserialize its details into an appropriate object.

should I make Report generic where the T represents the type of object it stores?

Should I add a property of type object to the report and somehow have the deserialization/casting as an external functionality

I just know that:

- In the future I want to easily be able to add more ReportTypes and more excel generators for that type
- If I retrieve a specific Report instance, I want to do it in a way that I should not know in advance what kind of Details object it stores

Is there any design pattern that could help me with getting my head around this kind of problems?

**UPDATE 1**: I think I haven't explained the problem properly. The key is in my second restriction, I don't know what type of Report I am dealing with.

I am storing reports in a no-SQL database (MongoDB without schema, which is storing objects Report and in the property DetailsTypeSpecific it can go anything, any object of any shape).

Suppose I want to retrieve a report with certain Id.
I go:

```
var report = _myRepo.GetReport("12f06eb1-213b-49af-9d41-44b25180aae9");
```

I want to be able to do

```
report.Export();
```

I cannot really use inheritance/polymorphism because I simply didn't deserialize my Json database record into any appropriate Report sub-type that would contain the excel generator, and polimorphism assumes I "know" already the subtype.

I could have an external export service that depending on the type uses one generator or another and do:

```
var exportedFile = _myExportService.Export(report);
```

That means that each time I add a new ReportType I have to modify MyExportService to add support for it. I wanted something more respectful of the open-close principle.

The main problem here is to have **something generic** to store data in Report that depends on the ReportType. That's what I don't know how to model.

Comment: Make different classes for teh Subreport types (all derived from teh same baseclass). Switch on the class via is statements? It sounds like a toutorial case for Inheritance and polymorphy.

Comment: You say you can't use polymorphism because you don't know what type of report you got from db! If you don't know what all reports you have to support, how can you model them? Using generics will still need you to have specialised forms of report/ data defined. Is the confusio inn DB layer when you retrieve and return report?

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: I'm not using an ORM, just the mongodb C# driver.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use plain old inheritance?

Something like:

```
public abstract class Report
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // You might be able to replace this polymorphism
    public ReportType ReportType { get; set; }

    public abstract Report Export();
}

public class DownloadsInfoReport : Report
{
    public object FileFormat { get; set; }

    public bool IsInCloud { get; set; }

    public string DownloadedThroughLink { get; set; }

    public override Report Export()
    {
        // Specific Export logic here
    }
}

public class ClicksInfoReport : Report
{
    public object UserClicking { get; set; }

    public int TimesClickedOnSamePage { get; set; }

    public override Report Export()
    {
        // Specific Export logic here
    }
}
```

Then you get the ability to do something like:

```
foreach (var report in allReports)
{
    report.Export();
}
```

Comment: In order to use polimorphism I need to instantiate a specific sub-type of Report, and as per my Update 1 I can't really know which subtype I've just retrieved from database.

Comment: I thought MongoDb was happy with inheritance: http://codingcanvas.com/storing-polymorphic-classes-in-mongodb-using-c/

Comment: You should follow this approach. Find a way to map data to mongodb. It is not a good design to extract properties that belong to a class and move them to another class, from OOD perspective.